# Can't find "Reverse Engineering File" while creating the Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs

Tags: hibernate, netbeans-8

I am using latest version of netbeans 8.0.2 to create a sample JSF+hibernate application. 
When I try to create the hibernate mapping files I can't find the reverse engineering file in the wizard Please check the image bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, your hibernate config file and reverse engineering file should be within the same package (folder structure) in the application. Try it.

Comment: restarting netbeans IDE can also fix this issue if they are both in the same package and it is still not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have them both in the same package and you still have this error. You can try to right click on your project and go the properties. Go then to libraries and add database jar file e.g. ojdbc7.jar for oracle and jconn3.jar for sybase. It should work after this.